# Vector product using map and reduce in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, vector, reduce

I'm trying to calculate the vector product between two vector using the map and reduce functions.

Let's see what happens in the REPL of Scala:

First of all I define 2 vectors with same length

```
scala> val v1 = Array(1,4,5,2)
v1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 4, 5, 2)

scala> val v2 = Array (3,5,1,5)
v2: Array[Int] = Array(3, 5, 1, 5)
```

Now I create a new array vecZip using the zip function

```
scala> val vecZip = v1 zip v2
vecZip: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,3), (4,5), (5,1), (2,5))
```

Now I'd like to apply the reduce method
(to do the product of each tuple) for each element of this array.
I thought this:

```
val vecToSum = vecZip.map(x=>(List(x).reduce(_*_)))
```

I want to get a list (vecToSum) where apply the reduce method to calculate the total result. However I get this error:

```
scala>  val vecToSum = vecZip.map(x=>(List(x).reduce(_*_)))
<console>:10: error: value * is not a member of (Int, Int)
    val vecToSum = vecZip.map(x=>(List(x).reduce(_*_)))
                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call map and multiply the tuples values with each other, like this:

```
val vecToSum = vecZip.map(x => x._1 * x._2)
```

`vecToSum` is a List of tuples, so `x` is a Tuple of `(Int, Int)`. Therefore if you call `List(x).reduce(...)`, you're creating a List with the only value being the tuple, so that's not really what you want.

Comment: I get this error:

    scala>  val vecToSum = vecZip.map(x=>x_.1 * x_.2)
    <console>:1: error: ')' expected but double literal found.
            val vecToSum = vecZip.map(x=>x_.1 * x_.2)
                                           ^

Comment: You got a typo in there :) It should be `x._1` not `x_.1`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

What your code is actually trying to do is it creates a list of a single tuple element, and then tries to reduce it. It would never work this way, as there is nothing to reduce - there is already single element in a list - a tuple.

Instead you need to map your vecZip array elements (tuples) via multiplying their elements:

```
vecZip.map { case (x, y) => x * y }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reduce here. Reducing an `Array[(Int, Int)]` would mean performing some associative binary operation on all tuples inside the array. Note that it could be performing the operation on the first couple of tuples, then on the result of that and the third tuple, then on the result of that and the fourth tuple etc. but also, due to associativity, it could perform the operation on first and second tuple, simultaneously on third and fourth tuple, and then on their results etc., which is nice for parallelization (and frameworks such as Spark rely on it heavily)).

For example you could sum all first elements and all second elements of each tuple:

```
val reduced = vecZip.reduce((pair1, pair2) => (pair1._1 + pair2._1, pair1._2 + pair2._2))
```

What you want however is to simply map each tuple into the product of its elements:

```
val vecToSum = vecZip.map { case (x, y) => x * y }
```

Note that I used the partial function (see that `case` over there) in order to perform pattern matching on the tuple; without the partial function it would look like this:

```
val vecToSum = vecZip.map(tuple => tuple._1 * tuple._2)
```